# JSON not being deserialized correctly on the server

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a javascript object on the client-side that has a SettingName and SettingValue properties.

#### Data Examples -

```
obj1.SettingName = "createdDate";
obj1.SettingValue = "10/07/2013";

obj2.SettingName = "arrayOfNames";
obj1.SettingValue = SomeArray; //An array of 5 strings

var settingsArray =new Array();
settingsArray[0] = obj1;
settingsArray[1] = obj2;

var settingsContainer = new Object;
settingsContainer.Settings = settingsArray;
```

#### ajax call -

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myURL",
        data: { settings: JSON.stringify(settingsContainer)},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

#### Server side class -

```
public class Setting
{        
    public string SettingName { get; set; }
    public object SettingValue { get; set; } //so this can hold multiple data types
}

public class SettingsContainer 
{
    public List<Setting> Settings { get; set;}
}
```

#### Controller action -

```
public ActionResult myURL(SettingsContainer settings) {
    //Here, the value for SettingsContainer.Settings[1].SettingValue, which 
      should be Array[5] i.e. on the C# side, I expect to see Object[5], 
      is only {object}. I'm not sure what's going on.

      Is my approach of handling this correct?
}
```

Any advise/help would be greatly appreciated. Thank-you!

Comment: Your Javascript doesn't seem to be initialising the variable `settings` anywhere.

Comment: There is a copy paste error: `obj1.SettingValue = Array[5];` Was this used in your test?

Comment: @MikeW, apologies, that was a typo

Comment: @TravisJ, corrected this. What I'm trying to do is pretty complicated, so I've tried to post a snippet of my code here. Hence the typos. I apologise.

Comment: Not sure why you expect to see object[5] when you have the property set to just object. Try changing it to be object[].

Answer (score 0):

On Server Side Method, you should use:

```
   public ActionResult myURL(string settings) {
       // deserialize the string to your object here;
    }
```

But you have to re-design your classes because they aren't supported for the
javascript deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'SettingValue' as `List<string>` or something that you are expecting. You cannot deserialize to object, because the deserializer doesn't know what is the object.

Answer (score 0):

try to set the data line in the ajax call as this

```
data: "{ 'settings':" +  JSON.stringify(settingsContainer)+"}",
```

(and maybe you can avoid the SettingsContainer and just use a vector or a list of settings as method argument).

The following code should help you solve the issue.

Codebehind:

```
public class helper
{
    public List<DoubleText> prop { get; set; }
}
public class DoubleText
{
    public string data1 { get; set; }
    public object data2 { get; set; }
}
[WebMethod]
public static string work(helper example)
{
// do stuff here
    return "ok";
}
```

javascript/jquery

```
var example = new Object();
        example.data1 = 'value';
        example.data2 = ['value1', 'value2'];

        var example2 = new Object();
        example2.data1 = 'value';
        example2.data2 = ['value1', 'value2'];

        var vector = new Array();
        vector[0] = example;
        vector[1] = example2;

        var ex = new Object();
        ex.prop = vector;


            var test = "{ 'example':" + JSON.stringify(ex) + "}";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/work.aspx/work',
                data: test,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    // stuff
                },
                error: function () { // other stuff}

            });
```